# How can I insert the contents of an SVG file into clipPath with PHP?

Tags: php, css, svg, clip-path

To make my code more DRY, I would like to be able to use an existing SVG file for a `clipPath`. For example:

picture-frame.svg:

```svg
<svg width="2000" height="1000" viewBox="0 0 2000 1000" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M932.66 998.369L932.251 ..." fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

example.php:

```html
...
<body>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 1000" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;">
      <defs>
          <clipPath id="my-clip">
              <?php echo insertSVG( 'picture-frame' ); ?>
          </clipPath>
      </defs>
  </svg>

  <div style="clip-path: url('#my-clip');">
    <img />
  </div>

</body>
...
```

The code to insert the SVG code is simple using `file_get_contents()`, see [this blog post](https://kevin-ang.medium.com/inline-svg-system-in-wordpress-or-php-development-838dad423e76).

The tricky part is `<clipPath>` [doesn't allow](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath) `<svg>` as a descendent, so copying the file contents verbatim does not work. Nor does using `SimpleXMLElement` to change `<svg>` to a tag with no-effect, like `<g>`.

How can I can insert just the contents of the root `<svg>` element (ie. `<path>` in my example above) into the `clipPath` element?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with using `DOMDocument()`:

```php
$svg = file_get_contents( $path );

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $svg );
$root = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'svg' )->item(0);

$nodes = array();
foreach ( $root->childNodes as $item ) {
  $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
  $dom2->formatOutput = true;
  $node = $dom2->importNode( $item, true ); // Import node
  $dom2->appendChild( $node ); // Append to root
  $nodes[] = preg_replace( "/<\\?xml.*\\?>/", '', $dom2->saveXML(), 1 ); // Strip XML declaration (optional)
}
return implode('', $nodes);
```

Result:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 2000 1000" xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px; overflow: hidden;">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="my-clip">
      <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M932.66 998.369L932.251 ..." fill="black"></path>
      <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M134.21 768.269L922.339 ..." fill="black"></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```